# Get the wrong response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I got the following code and I don't find the mistake.
When i execute it, I always get "no_request".

$username is equal to Reebal and $user is equal Simon

Ajax/jQuery

```
$("#cancel_friend").click(function(e){
    var user = "<?php echo $user_username; ?>";
    var type = "cancel_friend"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../system/friend_system.php",
        data: {
            user: user,
            type: type
        },
        success: function(data, status){
            if(data == "friend_request_canceled"){
                $("#cancel_friend").css("display", "none");
            }else{
                $(".error_msg_container").html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert(data);
        }
```

friend_system.php

```
}else if($_POST['type'] == "cancel_friend"){
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) friends WHERE user1 = '$username' AND user2 = '$user' AND accepted='0' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $request = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    if($request[0] > 0){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM friends WHERE user1 = '$username' AND user2 = '$user' AND accepted='0' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo "friend_request_canceled";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "no_request";
        exit();
    }
```

Here is the friends table:
[image]

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Where do you set `$username`? Did you tried debugging your code?

Comment: $username is in another php file, where I check the current logged in user. Yeah when I echo $username, I get 'Reebal'

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Okay, thx for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now on my phone so I can't look at it that well, your SQL Query is unsafe. Use either mysqli or pdo.
And you forgot the FROM your the sql query, here's an sql injection safe code:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName" , "dbPassword","dbUsername"); // connecting with PDO
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM friends WHERE user1 = :username AND user2 = :username2 AND accepted = \"0\" LIMIT 1"); // Preparing a query
$query->bindParam(":username" , $username,  PDO::PARAM_STR); // binding parameters in a safe way
$query->bindParam(":username2",$username2,PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(); // fetching the result and putting it in result
```

REMEMBER TO CHANGE THE VARIABLES AND MODIFY THE CONNECTION DETAILS
If it doesn't work comment not this comment

Comment: If anyone can edit my comment to make it look better that'd be good

Comment: Works! Thank you sir.

Comment: But can I use mysql_real_escape_string(); for the variables instead?

Comment: No, it doesn't help AT ALL

Comment: Real escape string just escapes characters and doesn't make it injection safe

Comment: BTW PDO actually does that for you, I just found that out(escapes the strings)